# How to prove a bug in this piece of code via unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, legacy

we have a habit in our company that when a bug is reported we do following steps:

1. Write a unit test that fails clearly showing the bug exists
2. Fix the bug
3. Re-run the test to prove the bug has been fixed
4. Commit the fix and the test to avoid regressions in the future

Now I came across a piece of legacy code with very easy bug. Situation looks like follows:

```
public final class SomeClass {
    ...
    public void someMethod(Parameter param) {
        try {
            if (param.getFieldValue("fieldName").equals("true")) { // Causes NullPointerException
                ...
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("Troubles ...", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that `fieldName` is not mandatory, so if not present, you get NPE. The obvious fix is:

```
if ("true".equals(param.getFieldValue("fieldName"))) {
    ...
}
```

My question is how to write a unit test to make the method fail. If I pass in a message which doesn't contain the `fieldName` it just logs the NPE but it won't fail ...

You may think what the method does? I can test the effect the method has. Unfortunatelly it communicates with some remote system so this will require a huge integration test which seems to be overkill with such a small and straiht-forward bug.

Note that it will be really hard if not impossible to make any changes in the code that are not directly causing the bug. So changing the code just to make it easier to test will probably not be an option. It's quite scary legacy code and everybody is really afraid to touch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do several things:

1. Stub the logger and check whether the error was logged or not as an indicator whether or not the bug occurred. You can use TypeMock or Moles if the logger can't be easily replaced.
2. Refactor the part inside the try block into its own method and call only that method inside the try block and make your unit test also call that method. Now the exception will not be silently logged and you can check whether or not it was thrown.

Comment: Yes, the refactoring of the inner part was my idea as well. I wanted to avoid any touch to the code but this might be quite safe. +1

Answer (score 2):

I think the best practice would be to mock out the logger, and assert that the logger has *not* been called for a pass. If it's a large change, I'm assuming the logger is used in a lot of places, which will help you with other tests in the future. For a quick-fix, you could raise an event in the exception catcher, but I don't think that's a very 'clean' way of doing it.

Comment: Might be an option but I don't feel too comfortable with detecting something on the Log side and failing a test upon it.

Comment: @Jan Zyka: What Rob suggests here is also the first of my suggestions in my answer. What you are testing in this case is interaction rather than result. Both ways are used in unit tests and are used dependent on the scenario you want to test.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO any catch all is wrong. You want to catch specific Exceptions, that you are looking for. Unit-testing is also about making the code better, so you can change it to

```
catch (ExpectedException ex)
```

Comment: Agree, but this is part of a HUGE code, nobody can say what consequences will it have if you let the Exception out of this method.

Comment: @Jan: Yep, but can anybody say if the state of the execution is still coherent after the exception has been thrown? In this case, since any exception would be hidden, "yes" is not an acceptable answer there... So the risk is identical in both letting the NPE out and hiding all exceptions.

Comment: You can't :) But letting the NPE out causing very probably termination of the whole thread ... Too risky I think

Answer (score 0):

The `log` could be an injected service, meaning that `SomeClass` looks like this:

```
public final class SomeClass 
{
    private final Logger log;

    public SomeClass(Logger log)
    {
        this.log = log;
    }
}
```

So in your unit test you could pass a fake `Logger` (possibly constructed with a [mocking framework](http://mockito.org/)) which allows you to detect whether or not a warning was logged during the test.

If `log` is a global variable, you could make that global variable writable so that you can replace the logger in your tests in a similar way.

Yet another option is to add a `Handler` to `log` in your unit test for the purpose of detecting `warn` calls (assuming that you are using [java.util.logging.Logger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html), but that doesn't seem to be the case because the method is [warning](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#warning%28java.lang.String%29), not `warn`).

Comment: Probably not the way I will take but +1 for a good tip. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, your companies method does mean you sometimes have to write a lot of extra tests, and you could argue if this is the way to go for this "obvious easy bug". But you're doing it for a reason.

I'd look at it like this:

- Your method should have a certain effect.
- It does not have this effect at the moment.
- If you want to fix it and test if the method works, you need to check the effect.

Therefore, you probably should write the whole code, even with the external systems, to proof the function works. Or in this case, doesn't.

Comment: Right, but this is not achievable in the moment. This is the huge integration test I wrote about. I will probably go with refactoring the inner part of the try-catch block in separate method. I think this could be considered as really safe change.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional logger appender at warn level for this class/logger at the beginning of the test (and remove it at the end).

Then run the `someMethod` and check if the new appender is still empty (then there was no exception) or has content (then there was a exception).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Boolean.toBoolean(String) or "true".equalsIgnoreCase(text)

If you don't want this behaviour you might want to add a test which shows that "True" and "TRUE" are treated as false.

Comment: Of course you are right, but believe me, if you saw the code this will be one of the latest thing to complain about :)